# python regex [.]+ should represents any single or repetitive character

Tags: python, regex

```
x='andi'
print re.search('an[.]+',x)
```

It returns `None`. Does it suppose to match the string.
In documentation the `.` (dot) can represents any character. And `+` means 1 or more repetition. So with `[.]+`, it should match `d` in the string.

Can anyone explain ? Why does it return `None`?

Comment: what do you think `[]` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use:

```
print re.search('an[.]+', x)
```

it matches **literal dot** since dot is inside `[ ]` i.e. a character class where special regex meta-characters loose their special meaning.

You should be using:

```
print re.search('an.+', x)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> print re.search('an.+', x).group()
andi
```

Comment: Doc citation: [Per the `re` docs for `[]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax): "Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. For example, `[(+*)]` will match any of the literal characters `'('`, `'+'`, `'*'`, or `')'`." (Note that character classes, e.g. `\w` still have special meaning, it's only special individual characters that lose special meaning).

Comment: @anubhava : sorry late response. This is perfecto man. I have used the [ ] not in the right place . Thanks a lot. :-)